# parametrize azure ml subscription name in pipeline

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

don't want to change all subscription names for every azurecli task is there a way I can add it as a parameter at the top of the pipeline for example azureSubscription='MYSUB'? then call it

```
trigger: 
  none

schedules:
- cron: "0 12 * * *"
  displayName: Daily build
  branches:
    include:
    - dev
  always: true
pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

variables:
  - group: ml-environment
    

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: Use Python 3.8
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.8'
    addToPath: true 


  # Invoke a Python script via Azure CLI in to use it's credentials
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MYSUB'
    scriptType: 'batch'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'python etl.py'
    workingDirectory: wd/scripts


# Invoke a Python script via Azure CLI in to use it's credentials
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'MYSUB'
        scriptType: 'batch'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: 'python example.py'
        workingDirectory: wd/scripts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can add the Azure Subscription value as parameter at the top of the pipeline and then use the parameters in next tasks.

Here is an example:

```
parameters:
- name: Subscription
  displayName: Azure Subscription
  type: string
  default: MYSUB
  values:
  - Azure
  - MYSUB
  
steps:

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.Subscription }}'
    scriptType: 'batch'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'python etl.py'
    workingDirectory: wd/scripts
```

When you run the pipeline, you can select the value of the Azure Subscription Name. The default value is MYSUB.

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)